# Mongoose deep populating multiple 2nd level objects not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a model `A` wit this field :

```
var field = {
    foo: String,
    b: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'B' }]
}
```

and model `B` with this feilds :

```
var field = {
    c: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'C' } // let's say this has 3 string field
    d: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'D' } // so was this
}
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444634/2889614) by [Trinh Hoang Nhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533738/trinh-hoang-nhu) by doing this-

```
 A.find({_id:req.params.id})
    .populate({ path: 'patient', model: Patient,
        populate: {
            path: 'b',
            model: B
        },
        populate: {
            path: 'c',
            model: C
        },
    })
    .exec(function (err, doc) {
        res.send(doc);
    })
```

-it should return the populated 2nd level and it did but the problem is it only `populate` the last `path` declared on the `.populate({})` function, in this case only the model `C` is populated. But when you changed it's position with model `B` then model `B` will be populated.

The query above returns something like this :

```
[
    {
        "foo":"Bar",
        "b": [
            {
                "c":"a32s1da4fas1a23s1da56s4c",
                "d":{
                    "foo1":"Bar1",
                    "foo2":"Bar2",
                    "foo3":"Bar3"
                }
            },
            {
                "c":"a32s1da4fas1a23s1da56s4d",
                "d":{
                    "foo1":"Bar1",
                    "foo2":"Bar2",
                    "foo3":"Bar3"
                }
            }
            // so on ...
        ]
    }
]
```

I was expecting something like this :

```
[
    {
        "foo":"Bar",
        "b": [
            {
                "c":{
                    "foo1":"Bar1",
                    "foo2":"Bar2",
                    "foo3":"Bar3"
                },
                "d":{
                    "foo1":"Bar1",
                    "foo2":"Bar2",
                    "foo3":"Bar3"
                }
            },
            {
                "c":{
                    "foo1":"Bar1",
                    "foo2":"Bar2",
                    "foo3":"Bar3"
                },
                "d":{
                    "foo1":"Bar1",
                    "foo2":"Bar2",
                    "foo3":"Bar3"
                }
            }
            // so on ...
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I dont know why it even accepted multiple `populate` keys in the object, it is already duplicated, 
what you specified to populate is:

```
 populate: {
            path: 'b',
            model: B
        },
        populate: {
            path: 'c',
            model: C
        },
```

here the property `populate` gets duplicated, and only the last one defined is considered.

You need to specify the populate paths once as an array. So your populate property would become:

```
 populate: [{
            path: 'b',
            model: B
        },{
            path: 'c',
            model: C
        }]
```

And the query is,

```
A.find({_id:req.params.id})
    .populate({ path: 'patient', model: Patient,
        populate: [{
            path: 'b',
            model: B
        },{
            path: 'c',
            model: C
        }],
    })
    .exec(function (err, doc) {
        res.send(doc);
    })
```

Comment: Oh God! Thanks Naeem! I haven't noticed that.

Comment: saves me some time!! http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate

Comment: Big Thanks man ! I was struggling with that use case. I still think that we might avoid using mongoose and rather work with the native nodejs mongodb driver.