# Mongoose select in two level population

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

i have such query

```
 Order.find({patient:req.user._id})
        .populate({
            path:'doctor',
            populate:{
                path:'specialization',
                select:'-_id'
            },
        })
```

in this query, if I remove select - everything is working, but when i want select fields which i want (not all ), (select as option working on first level population ) populate no working, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

This may be occurring because your nested `populate` is an option for `.populate({})` and thus may not have a `select` option. See the **Populating across multiple levels** section of [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) documentation.

You could also try recursively populating. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18235518/5737121) answer for more details.