# populate multiple sub documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a user with a group reference. i'm wondering how i populate the game, users and ranks within the group? so what i basically want is to populate these 3 values in the `user.group` in the code

**user mode**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  fb: {
    type: SchemaTypes.Long,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  name: String,
  birthday: Date,
  country: String,
  image: String,
  group: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group'}

});
```

**group model**

```
var groupSchema = new Schema({
  users: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }],
  game: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Game' },
  ranks: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ladder'
  }]

});
```

**code**

```
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(params.id, {$set:{group:object._id}}, {new: true}, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(user);
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongoose 4 supports populate over multiple levels. [Populate Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) If your schema is:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  friends: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});
```

Then you can use:

```
User.
  findOne({ name: 'Val' }).
  populate({
    path: 'friends',
    // Get friends of friends - populate the 'friends' array for every friend
    populate: { path: 'friends' }
  });
```

So in your case it should be something like:

```
User.findById(params.id)
.populate({
  path: 'group',
  populate: {
    path: 'users game ranks'
  }
})
.exec( function(err, user){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(user);
    }
  })
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077609/mongoose-populate-embedded)