# Is it possible to have an array of alternative subdocument schemas in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Is it possible to have an array of alternative subdocument schemas in mongoose?**

For instance, take this made up scenario: if i have a main schema for a person and i have a field called vehicles of type array, i want to be able to define sub document schemas, but for each vehicle type (car, motorbike, bike, bus etc etc ) :

```
var car = new mongoose.Schema({
    make: { type: String, required: true, default: 'Ford', trim: true },
    model: { type: String, trim: true },
    wheels: Number,
});
var motorbike = new mongoose.Schema({
    make: { type: String, required: true, default: 'Honda', trim: true },
    model: { type: String, trim: true },
    seats: Number,
});
var bike = new mongoose.Schema({
    make: { type: String, required: true, default: 'MuddyFox', trim: true },
    model: { type: String, trim: true },
    lights: Number,
});
var bus = new mongoose.Schema({
    make: { type: String, required: true, default: 'MAN', trim: true },
    model: { type: String, trim: true },
    dents: Number,
});

/* person */
var person = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, default: 'Joe Bloggs', trim: true },
    timeCreated: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
    vehicles: [car, motorbike, bike, bus] /* this is what i want to do */
});

db.model('person', person);
```

Note the person schema.

So that person can have any of those vehicles, but the data for each vehicle is still validated against it's own schema.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't even realise it was possible to have no comments after 2 months of posting on SO!

Comment: Wow, this was exactly the question I was looking for, but sadly, no one has answered it. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not! I don't think it is possible in any case. You are probably better off having different collections, for each subdoc (vehicle) and then using the vehicles array to store the _ids - in addition, i would store the owner _id in each vehicle schema too.

Comment: i think you can do it with manual validation, for example on ``pre('save')``

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contributions. This is an important question seeing how mongoose usually nullifies the advantages of schema-less databases and I wish this would be addressed in mongoose core.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mongoose plugin called mongoose-schema-extend, that will allow you to enable Schema Inheritance for Mongoose, and basically I think, you are looking for this functionality.

Please check the github project:

- https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend

You can create a `Vehicle` schema, add it as an array to the `Person` schema, and extend the `Vehicle` for your different type of vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any examples of multiple embedded documents being passed as an array.

Perhaps you could rejig things like this:

```
var car = new mongoose.Schema({
    make: { type: String, required: true, default: 'Ford', trim: true },
    model: { type: String, trim: true },
    wheels: Number,
});
var motorbike = new mongoose.Schema({
    make: { type: String, required: true, default: 'Honda', trim: true },
    model: { type: String, trim: true },
    seats: Number,
});
var bike = new mongoose.Schema({
    make: { type: String, required: true, default: 'MuddyFox', trim: true },
    model: { type: String, trim: true },
    lights: Number,
});
var bus = new mongoose.Schema({
    make: { type: String, required: true, default: 'MAN', trim: true },
    model: { type: String, trim: true },
    dents: Number,
});

var transport = new mongoose.Schema({
    car: [car],
    motorbike: [motorbike],
    bike: [bike],
    bus: [bus]
});

/* person */
var person = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true, default: 'Joe Bloggs', trim: true },
    timeCreated: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
    vehicles: [transport]
});

db.model('person', person);
```

If that doesn't work, then as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137239/querying-nested-embedded-documents-with-mongoose) you can use [mongoose populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). This method is now more effective following the addition of  [deep population was added in Mongoose Deep 3.6](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1377#issuecomment-15911192).

So you could do soemthing like:

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

There's also a mongoose plugin to aid with this functionality called [mongoose-deep-populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate) which is very up-to-date.